# When I had 2 UI control bind to a same property, how do I only update a UI that I want?

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

For exmaple I got 2 TextBlock UI.

the current code below is that both window will get the name
whenever INotifyPropertyChanged is call.

For example I window 2 will get name being updated but
I didn't want window 1 to get updated when INotifyPropertyChanged is call.

**Window 1**

```
<TextBlock Text="{binding Name}"/>
```

**Window 2**

```
<TextBlock Text="{binding Name}"/>
```

**View Model**

```
class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        private string m_Name = "John";

        public string Name 
        {
            get { return m_Name; }
            set 
            {
                if (value != Name)
                {
                    m_Name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: If you don't want it to be updated then don't bind to the property in the first place. Just set the value manually from code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Add a one-time setting for the binding mode to the one that you don't want to update.

```
{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}
```

Comment: Hi John Bowen, thank for the answer. Well it a good idea but it didn't work if I am using INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: If you're seeing the value change when using this that means you're reloading the control itself which has nothing to do with the change notification on this property.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop a UI control from being updated by the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface just at particular times. However, you can simply add another property to bind to your `Window` 1 and source the value of this from your original property. You can then add a `bool` property which enables or disables the update of the new property. Try something like this:

```
public string SecondNameProperty
{
    get 
    {
        if (CanUpdate) secondNameProperty = Name;
        return secondNameProperty;
    }
}
```

When you want the `SecondNameProperty` property to update, just ensure that the `CanUpdate` property is set to `true` and when you don't want it to be updated, set it to `false`.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, thanks for the answer. Your idea is good but I wish I could minimize the code. How I wish that the name of the UI control I define in window that I could get it in view model. I am not sure is that possible in MVVM though.

Comment: WPF is verbose... it requires lots of code to be written. You're better off just accepting this fact and moving on.